# C# Dapper: Getting multiple result sets from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, dapper

[image: SP response image]

My SP returns data like below. When I use dapper QueryMultipleAsync, it seems to be picking only 2nd result set and when use queryAsync it picks only first result set. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

```
col1    col2    col3
123      name   23.34

time    value   
25:17.0 123 
25:17.0 124 
25:17.0 543 
25:17.0 566 

col1    col2    col3
123     name1   23.34

time    value   
25:17.0 123 
25:17.0 124 
25:17.0 543 
25:17.0 566
```

Comment: How does your code look?

Comment: Post your Dapper code, ensure that you are using the GridReader (Result of QueryMultiple) Correctly, and its reading various result sets, what happens when you try to read 3rd or 4th result set . Ensure that MARS property is enabled in the Connection string, to support the working of the QueryMultiple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `QueryMulitpleAsync` you can read result sets one by one. Here is an example that works for me:

```
[Test]
public async Task MultipleSpResultsWithDapper()
{
    // Act
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YourDatabase"))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        var result = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync(
            "YourStoredProcedureName",
            new { param1 = 1, param2 = 2 }, 
            null, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        // read as IEnumerable<dynamic>
        var table1 = await result.ReadAsync();
        var table2 = await result.ReadAsync();

        // read as typed IEnumerable
        var table3 = await result.ReadAsync<Table1>();
        var table4 = await result.ReadAsync<Table2>();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(table1);
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(table2);
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(table3);
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(table4);
    }
}
```

Entity classes:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int col1 { get; set; }

    public string col2 { get; set; }

    public double col3 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    public string time { get; set; }

    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

Stored procedure declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].YourStoredProcedureName
(
    @param1 int, 
    @param2 int
)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Almost. but i had to loop, So did something like this. List<table1> resp = new List<table1>();
                        while (!resultsets.IsConsumed){
                            var table1 = new Table1();
                            table1 = resultsets.ReadAsync<Table1>().Result.First();
                            table1.table2 = resultsets.ReadAsync<Table2>().Result.ToList();
                            resp.Add(table1 );
                        }

Comment: So far your SP returns the sequence Table1 => Table2 => Table1 => Table2 and etc, it should work well.